# Autoplay Cross-Browser

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio

Como faço pra dar autoplay em todos(ou quase todos) os navegadores mobile e desktop?

```
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Aparentemente este código retirado [daqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp), não funciona.
Alguem sabe alguma forma de fazer isto usando JavaScript ou HTML puro ou qualquer outra tecnologia?

Sei que várias pessoas vão dizer que isso é uma má prática, mas é para uma web-radio.

Comment: Penso que para telemóvel não há possibilidade de fazer autoplay por causa de certas politicas, pelo menos se for usado no chrome

Comment: Realmente, acho que isso não tem solução...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em uma resposta curta, não é possível usar o autoplay em `<audio>` e `<video>`.

Isso porque sites que reproduzem áudio automaticamente (ou vídeos com faixa de áudio) podem ser uma experiência desagradável para os usuários, é preferível serem evitados sempre que possível.

Para ativar a reprodução automática só estará disponível se o usuário habilitar por conta própria, e também tem algumas situações *limitadas* que permitirão o autoplay, segue todas situações comum na maioria dos navegadores:

1. Se o áudio estiver mudo ou definido com volume `0` (em caso de vídeos pode ser interessante, geralmente usado para animações)
2. O usuário interagiu com o site clicando, tocando, pressionando teclas, etc.
3. Se o site foi permitido; isso pode acontecer automaticamente se o navegador determinar que o usuário se envolve com a mídia com frequência ou manualmente por meio de preferências ou outros recursos da interface do usuário
4. Se a política de recurso de reprodução automática for usada para conceder suporte de reprodução automática a um `<iframe>` e seu documento, algo como: `<iframe src="https://cross-origin/foobar" allow="autoplay">`

   - [atributo allow no iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy/Using_Feature_Policy#the_iframe_allow_attribute)
   - [politicas do autoplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy/autoplay)

Existem características que variam entre diferentes navegadores/motores, pode ler com mais detalhes em:

- [Chromium](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)
- [Webkit](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)
- [Politicas `<video>` no iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Como disse, se o site for permitido ele poderá reproduzir automaticamente, mas isso é escolha do usuário, nos navegadores Desktop baseados no Chromium, geralmente (pode variar) irão executar o autoplay (dentro das condições citadas no link que informei acima), já no Firefox se não estiver na lista de permissão você irá obter uma mensagem no [console (devtools)](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/):

> A reprodução automática só é permitida quando aprovada pelo usuário, ou o site foi ativado pelo usuário, ou a mídia está com som desativado.

Ainda no Firefox, é possível que o **usuário habilite manualmente** quais sites podem executar automaticamente, isso pode ser feito clicando no ícone na barra de endereços ou no endereço `about:preferences#privacy`.

Comment: Obrigado @guilherme-nascimento isso era para uma web rádio, logo, o autoplay de audio não seria uma experiência desagradável, e sim uma experiência esperada, tentei por anos, sem solução por enquanto, de qualquer forma muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @sistematico nesse caso abrir um pop-up (div) com um botão play solicita do que o usuario clique por conta, assim chamando o método play do seu elemento áudio, deverá resolver

Answer (score -1):

Não deve funcionar porque não tens o ficheiro na tua directoria. `horse.mp3` e `horse.ogg` não devem existir, faz com link directo:

```
src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg"
```

e

```
src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3"
```

Ou então faz download para a tua directoria de trabalho dos ficheiros `horse.mp3` e `horse.ogg`.

Comment: O ficheiro existe, e quando aperto o botão a música toca, o problema é o autoplay, se funcionar somente no PC já está bom pra mim.